# how do you loop through a List based on List contents

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have a transaction object:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public int transactionId {get;set;}
    public string itemName {get;set;}
    public int quantity {get;set;}
}
```

A List of transactions could look like this (serialized for your reading convenience):

```
[{transactionId: 1, itemName: 'foo', quantity: 5},
{transactionId: 1, itemName: 'bar', quantity: 5},
{transactionId: 2, itemName: 'example', quantity: 5}]
```

A transaction can hold several items. I want to loop through the list above based on every transactionId. I want to turn a Transaction into something like this:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public int transactionId {get;set;}
    public List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>{};
}
```

For every unique transactionid, loop through all associated items and put them in the itemList variable. When serialized, you would then end up with:

```
[{transactionId: 1, {{itemName: 'foo', quantity: 5}, {itemName: 'bar', quantity: 5}},
transactionId: 2, {{itemName: 'example', quantity: 5}}}]
```

What needs to be done: loop through all transactions in a list, and for every unique transactionid, put it's itemName and quantity variables in the itemList object as a new Item object. Something like:

```
foreach(unique transactionId in item)
{
    item[transactionId].itemList.itemName = item[transactionId].itemName;
    item[transactionId].itemList.quantity= item[transactionId].quantity;
}
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Shouldn't `itemName` and `quantity` be part of `Item`?

Comment: Typo! I edited the code.

Comment: So the real issue is that you have some data that is in the wrong format that you need to put into the correct format?

Comment: Sounds like you need a `GroupBy`

Comment: You defined to Transaction class, first separate from each other

Comment: What's your goal from Item class?

Comment: what should be the results of  `[{transactionId: 1, itemName: 'foo', quantity: 5}, {transactionId: 1, itemName: 'foo', quantity: 2}]`?? 1) `[{transactionId: 1, {{itemName: 'foo', quantity: 7}}]` or 2) `[{transactionId: 1, {{itemName: 'foo', quantity: 5}, {itemName: 'foo', quantity: 2}}]` @BasR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfect scenario for [`GroupBy` LINQ operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb545971.aspx) version:

```
List<Transaction> transactions = new List<Transaction>();
var groupedTransactions =
    transactions.GroupBy(t => t.transactionId, (key, values) =>
    new TransactionGroup()
    {
        transactionId = key,
        itemList = values.Select(v =>
            new Item()
            {
                itemName = v.itemName,
                quantity = v.quantity
            }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

assuming classes as:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public int transactionId { get; set; }
    public string itemName { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionGroup
{
    public int transactionId { get; set; }
    public List<Item> itemList = new List<Item> { };
}

public class Item
{
    public string itemName { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using here [one of its overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb549393(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TSource>, TResult> resultSelector
)
```

where you specify what is the key for grouping and what do you want to do with each group values.

Comment: this does not work if the the initial items are like this. [{transactionId: 1, itemName: 'foo', quantity: 5}, {transactionId: 1, itemName: 'foo', quantity: 2}]

Comment: @HPT, not sure if it is the issue for OP... You assume he would like group items then, which is not so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate the data and mold it to the form you need. In this code the summary will contain one transaction object per id with all it's items.

```
var summary = new Dictionary<int, Transaction>();
foreach(var item in items)
{
    Transaction t;
    if(!summary.TryGetValue(item.Id, t)) 
    {
        t = new Transaction(item.Id);
        summary[t.Id] = t;
    }

    t.Items.Add(new Item { quantity = item.quantity, itemName = item.itemName});
}
```

Comment: this does not work if the the initial items are like this. [{transactionId: 1, itemName: 'foo', quantity: 5}, {transactionId: 1, itemName: 'foo', quantity: 2}]

Answer (score 0):

Use `GroupBy`:

```
public class Transaction2
{
    public int transactionId { get; set; }    
    public List<Item> itemList = new List<Item> { };    
    public class Item
    {
        public string itemName { get; set; }    
        public int quantity { get; set; }
    }
}

....

var list = new List<Transaction>
{
    new Transaction { transactionId = 1, itemName = "foo", quantity = 5 },
    new Transaction { transactionId = 1, itemName = "bar", quantity = 5 },
    new Transaction { transactionId = 2, itemName = "example", quantity = 5 },
};

var list2 = list
    .GroupBy(z => z.transactionId)
    .Select(z => new Transaction2
        {
            transactionId = z.Key,
            itemList = z
                .Select(z2 => new Transaction2.Item 
                {
                    itemName = z2.itemName, 
                    quantity = z2.quantity 
                })
                .ToList()
        })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: this does not work if the the initial items are like this. [{transactionId: 1, itemName: 'foo', quantity: 5}, {transactionId: 1, itemName: 'foo', quantity: 2}]

Comment: it should results in [{transactionId: 1, {{itemName: 'foo', quantity: 7}}] but it will results in [{transactionId: 1, {{itemName: 'foo', quantity: 5}, {itemName: 'foo', quantity: 2}}]

Comment: @HPT You assume the OP wants to group by itemName and addition quantities, what in the question makes you think that?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you are going to call your old transaction OldTransaction and you will create in it a method called ToItem. I'm calling the Transaction class the one you really want:

```
public Item ToItem() { return new Item(itemName, itemQuantity); }
```

Then you read in old transactions in to a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, Transaction> dict = new Dictionary<int, Transaction>();
foreach (OldTransaction ot in whateverSource) {
    Transacton t = null;
    if (!dict.TryGet(ot.ID, out t)) {
        t = new Transaction(ot.ID);
        dict.Add(ot.ID, t);
    }
    t.items.Add(ot.ToItem());
}
```

At this point you can iterate through the values in dict and you have what you want.

Comment: this does not work if the the initial items are like this. [{transactionId: 1, itemName: 'foo', quantity: 5}, {transactionId: 1, itemName: 'foo', quantity: 2}]

Comment: Not spelled out in the problem statement.